# CSS and Bootstrap - full page image not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, image

So I'm trying to make it so that a full page image shows in the page, and resizes responsively on different screens so that it always takes up the whole screen. I looked it up on w3schools and other questions on Stack, but it seems that no matter what I do it never works, I checked if something is overriding my CSS in the browser developer tools but it seems there is nothing wrong, it just simply doesnt work. I'm using bootstrap and the div which background image should be full page is a col-12, would that cause the problem? This is my css:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
}

#image-div {
    background-image: url("paper.jpeg");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    background-blend-mode:darken !important; 
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<div className="row" id="calculator-row">
          <div className="col-12" id="image-div">
            <div className="over-image">
              <p class="try-calculator">
               Calculate the possible return of investments
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="col-12" id="calculator-div">
            <h1>Return of Investments</h1>
            <BenefitCalculator />
                <strong>*The average conversion percent is 4, but enter yours in case you know it</strong>
          </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Forgot to mention I am also using REACTJS

Comment: add your html too pls

Comment: Yes, please add your HTML. This also assumes that the URL path to the image is correct, is that right?

Comment: Yes, the image is shown, its height is just not full screen and not responsive @ton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `backgound-size: cover, contain;`
If this does not work send an example of you code. Also height in percentage is always a bad idea. If this is for the element to be as tall as the page use 100vh or some other method. Also note that you will probably need a media query for portrait and landscape orientation.

Comment: Thank you, that did it!

Answer (score 1):

Try this snippit:

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin-right: -15px;
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.row-fw {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.col-12 {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}

#image-div {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/g/1920/1080");
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-blend-mode: darken !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class="row row-fw">
    <div id="image-div"></div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

You could also be using `height: 100vh;` & `width: 100vw;` (vw = viewport width, vh = viewport height).

If the parent gets bigger than the size of your screen, so will the background. `100vw` & `100vh` will only use the viewport width & height.

Comment: Sorry, this isn't working, it's looking just the same as before.

Comment: Actually this works as well but only with 100vh instead of 100%

Comment: Add an extra class to the row element with this css:
`height: 100vh;
width: 100vw;`

I updated the answer

Comment: this is the code that I need. thank you. I just add !important as per my need   `#image-div {
  background-image: url("https://placekitten.com/g/1920/1080.png");
 background-position: center!important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat!important;
  background-size: cover!important;
  height: 100%!important;
  display: block!important;
  width: 100%!important;
  color: white!important;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)!important;
  background-blend-mode: darken !important;
  font-size: 20px;
}`

Answer (score 0):

just add below class to the parent div of image, it will scale itself as per screen sizes.
.img-responsive -> Makes an image responsive (will scale nicely to the parent element).

Comment: What do you mean by below class? Also the image is technically a background image, not a child of the parent div.